# Hibernate Annotations with SQL query

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I want to create a hibernate SQL query and cast it to an object without creating the table.

for example i have

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.append("SELECT groupId, categoryId, name FROM AssetCategory");

SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(query.toString());
sqlQuery.addEntity("Categories", Categories.class);

List<Categories> list = sqlQuery.list();
```

The category object is declared like this :

```
@Entity
public class Categories implements Serializable {

@Column(name = "name")
String name;

@Column(name = "categoryId")
Long categoryId;

@Column(name = "groupId")
Long groupId;
```

Of course this cant work because there is no ID. And this table does not need to be created either. So how would i go about declaring this ?

Any hints ?

I just cant find the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a SQLTransformer to do this.. you wont need the annotations in the pojo even.

[read this.](http://relation.to/2133.lace) it will help you realize what you should be doing.